# Testing solution from Exercism

Tags: dart

I just installed Exercism and would like to test if I managed to complete the hello-world assignment. 
I changed the hello_world.dart file in the lib folder to print the solution, but now I am struggling with running the test file.

In the guide it says to simply run

```
$ pub run test
```

Is the $-sign meant to mean something to me? Cause all I am getting is: "'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file." I have the same issue with running "pub get" or "pub run test". (What does pub mean?)

To summarize, I ran:

```
exercism configure "my token"
exercism download --exercise=hello-world --track=dart
cd C:\Users\Martin\exercism\dart\hello-world
```

I changed the file in C:\Users\Martin\Exercism\dart\hello-world\lib
And then I tried

```
$ pub run test
pub run test
pub get
```

And none of these seem to do anything. So, I don't know how to test my file.

I do have flutter installed and run is fine with Android Studio, if that is relevant. It seems to me that I can choose to write the solution in both notepad++ or Android Studio.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

`pub` is package manager for dart programming language, just like `npm` for javascript. Since you've installed it on WINDOWS i'm guessing you used `choco` - package manager to install the `dart-sdk`. https://dart.dev/get-dart.

Once installed make sure you've set `dart-sdk` the path in Environment variable.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the issue was with the installation. Since I had been using Android Studio I assumed everything was in order, but I had to have dart installed separately.